# Python Global http connection, refactor

Tags: python

I have a python script that was created initially with a global http connection. I need to pass the url on the command line so I can no longer init the connection in globals.

my first attempt that seems to work is to just define conn in global and use like so

```
conn={}

def sendrequest(args)
   global conn
   conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(url.hostname,url.port)
...
```

Is there a better option? I was thinking pass as a parameter but it used so in 24 functions and that seems like a lot of duplication.

The script is used by an automated app that will call it by passing multiple parameters. The change is to make it be able to pass the URL for dev, UAT prod.

Comment: Put all the methods in a class & make `conn` a class attribute?

Comment: Can you give more context/code as to how this `conn` is initialized? What are its contents? Would it be easier to just wrap your 24+ functions in a class?

Comment: Use dependency injection (aka pass in as a parameter)

Comment: it doesn't matter if you pass url on command line or not - `conn` still can be `global`. But it would be better to create connection outside functions and send as parameter to functions - like `def sendrequest(args, conn)`. And it doesn't matter it is a lot og duplication - it will be more readable and simpler to debug problems.